# Jquery как получить значения из ячеек строки таблицы

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Есть такой код в asp.net webforms:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdRole" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="NormalText" Width="100%" OnRowDataBound="grdRole_OnRowDataBound">
        <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="NormalText"/>
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#fb9d00" CssClass="BlackHeader"/>
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="UserName" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="User Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="First Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Last Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CreatedOn" ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Created on"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Role"/>

            <asp:ButtonField ItemStyle-Width="5%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ControlStyle-CssClass="Button" CommandName="BindUserFields" Text="Edit" HeaderText="" ButtonType="Link" CausesValidation="False"/>
```

То есть некий гридвью делает таблицу с кнопкой `edit`.
Нужно каким-то образом получить через jquery значения всех ячеек той строки в таблице, где находится эта кнопка. То есть суть такова, что при нажатии на кнопку `edit` у меня появляется popup, с полями, которые должны быть заполнены, данными из ячеек строки, в которой была нажата кнопка. Как это можно сделать ? Пробовал через parent , но не вышло ничего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вас такая функция интересует ?

```js
$('table button').click(function(e) {
  var tds = $(this).parent('td').siblings('td');
  var row = [];
  $.each(tds, function(i, c) {
    row.push($(c).text());
  });
  $('#result').text(row.join(' '));
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>r1c1</td>
    <td>r1c2</td>
    <td>
      <button>Click me</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>r2c1</td>
    <td>r2c2</td>
    <td>
      <button>Click me</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>r3c1</td>
    <td>r3c2</td>
    <td>
      <button>Click me</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="result"></div>
```